# Estimating WTA (or WTP) from a logit model

Tags: regression, probability, logistic, transportation

I am a beginner at writing and estimating models and will appreciate the community's help.

I have some data on whether individuals accepted or rejected some tasks that they were assigned.

Here's a simple summary of the data I have

- Length of the task in minutes (Len) [this changes at random within a given range]
- Payment offered for completing the task (Pay) [this changes at random within a given range]
- Whether individual i accepted or rejected the task

I will model their choice as a discrete choice model, such that the probability of accepting by individual i of task k ($P_{ik}$)

$$ P_{ik} = \alpha_{0} + \beta_{1} Pay_k + \beta_{2} Len_k + \epsilon_{ik}$$

(I am assuming error term is distributed iid extreme value)

I will estimate the model using a logit-type specification.

**My goal is to estimate their willingness to accept (money for the task in exchange for the time they will spend on the task), i.e. WTA**

When I run the logit equation and get back coefficients for $\hat{\beta_{0}}, \hat{\beta_{1}}, \hat{\beta_{2}}$ , **do I need to transform the coefficients in any way (since these are logit coefficients) before taking the ratio of $\beta_{1}$ and $\beta_{2}$ to estimate WTA?**

Finally, how would this change if I was observing each individual's accept/reject choices repeatedly? For example, if they were offered these tasks 5 times (and the lengths and payments changed completely at random each time)

I will appreciate your help, even if you cannot answer the latter (repeated observation) part of my question.

If I have left out key information needed to answer this question, please let me know.